# Reduce Realm file dimension

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

I got this error while writing and modifying thousand of record:

`Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size`

And I found out that this is due to the dimension that the transaction occupy on the device memory.
So I split the single, big transaction in smaller transactions and now I don't get the error anymore. But I noticed that the default.realm file is getting bigger.
I read that if the application does a lot of transactions this is normal, because each transaction also write a log in the same file where the data is stored

Is there a way to clear the unnecessary data? 
I already use Realm.compactRealm at the application startup but this doesn't seems to free all the unused space.

Comment: This happens primarily if you have open Realm instances on non-looper background threads that are never closed. Very common if you do anything like `Realm.getDefaultInstance().someMethod()`.

Comment: I always do `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { ... }`it should close it automatically this way

Comment: Yes, yes it should. Maybe you really just have 2 GB+ data?